# How to aggregate a column based on values of other columns - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case, aggregate-functions

Say I have a table:

| date | fruit | status | numberOfFruits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | apple | ripe | 3 |
| 2022-01 | banana | mature | 5 |
| 2022-01 | pear | ripe | 10 |
| 2022-01 | grapes | mature | 9 |
| 2022-02 | apple | ripe | 3 |
| 2022-02 | banana | mature | 3 |
| 2022-02 | pear | ripe | 3 |
| 2022-02 | grapes | mature | 7 |

I want to be able to create a query that adds 3 aggregate columns (AVG, MIN, MAX) that aggregates the column `numberOfFruits` based on their `status` and `date`, ordered by `fruit` and `date`. The output of the table should be:

| date | fruit | status | numberOfFruits | AvgNumOfFruits | MaxNumOfFruits | MinNumOfFruits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | apple | ripe | 3 | 6.5 | 10 | 3 |
| 2022-01 | pear | ripe | 10 | 6.5 | 10 | 3 |
| 2022-01 | banana | mature | 5 | 7 | 9 | 5 |
| 2022-01 | grapes | mature | 9 | 7 | 9 | 5 |
| 2022-02 | apple | ripe | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022-02 | pear | ripe | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022-02 | banana | mature | 3 | 5 | 7 | 3 |
| 2022-02 | grapes | mature | 7 | 5 | 7 | 3 |

I'm at a loss and here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    date, 
    fruit, 
    status,
    numberOfFruits,
    AVG(CASE WHEN "status" = 'ripe' THEN "numberOfFruits" ELSE "numberOfFruits" END) as AvgNumOfFruits, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN "status" = 'ripe' THEN "numberOfFruits" ELSE "numberOfFruits" END) as MingNumOfFruits,
    MAX(CASE WHEN "status" = 'ripe' THEN "numberOfFruits" ELSE "numberOfFruits" END) as MaxNumOfFruits
FROM fruitdata
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY date, status
```

The query just repeats the `numberofFruits` for those 3 aggregate columns. It should be like "take the average of the column `numberOfFruits` that has the `status` of ripe, as well as the `date` 2022-01, and put it in a new column called `AvgNumOfFruits`. Somehow I can't translate this to SQL.

Any advice/tips/help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simplify this a bit: `avg("numberOfFruits") filter (where status = 'ripe')` but if you want `avg()`, `min()` and `max()` there is no way to avoid writing three expressions. Btw: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers.

Comment: Three expressions, each getting the aggregate values? i.e. 1 expression that gets avg(), one for min(), and one for max(), then just "combining" them in the end? Sorry still working on my sql skills.

Comment: It sounds like you want to GROUP BY less things... try GROUP BY 1,2 or GROUP BY 1,2,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation functions are employed to aggregate rows (combining rows to get aggregated values). In your case you should rather use window functions, that compute values over windows (partitions/groups of rows), though without aggregating the rows.

```
SELECT *,
       AVG(numberOfFruits) OVER(PARTITION BY date, status) AS AvgNumOfFruits, 
       MAX(numberOfFruits) OVER(PARTITION BY date, status) AS MaxNumOfFruits,
       MIN(numberOfFruits) OVER(PARTITION BY date, status) AS MinNumOfFruits 
FROM fruitdata
ORDER BY date,
         status DESC
```

The corresponding window functions need to be computed on groups of "*date*" and "*status*" fields. On the other hand, the ordering is completely optional and up to you (`ORDER BY` clause).

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJ7ToA8cgb8egWBgXVMA37/0).